# Gitlab6 clone not working

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have Gitlab6 setup at 192.168.1.74:8001. I want to access that gitlab from 192.168.1.73. I have a account in that and created a new project. Now I want to clone that project by command "git clone git@192.168.1.74:user1/sample-project.git".

It prompted me for password saying "git@192.168.1.74's password: " and I dont know the password as there is no git user on 192.168.1.74. I tried with my gitlab pass but failed. I have already added my shh public keys to my gitlab account.

How to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You setup GitLab but there's no git user? You have a non-standard setup then-- you might get more help if you specify how your configuration differs from GitLab's default.